# Can we use "Eval" to dynamically Enable or disable a control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, eval

```
   <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsSignificantRegistration" runat="server" 
                AutoPostBack="True" />

   <asp:TextBox ID="txtSignificantOtherName" ReadOnly='<%# cbIsSignificantRegistration.Checked %>' runat="server" class="tblTxt" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>

   <asp:Button ID="btnSignificantOtherSearch" runat="server" Enabled='<%# cbIsSignificantRegistration.Checked %>' OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Search" />
```

Refering to the code above I want to Enable a TextBox and Button if the CheckBox is Checked by the user and vice versa. And I want to do the same without firing CheckChanged Event of Checkbox.

Is it possible using Eval in ASP.NET, just like I've used it in code above.

Note: I've already used the code above and its not working in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET is server side so this will only set the enabled state on load of the page. Any user interaction after that will not be triggered.

The best solution would be to use Javascript to trigger an event to enable/disable the textbox.

Using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".chk").change(function(){
        $(".txt").attr("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked")); 
    });
});

<asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsSignificantRegistration" runat="server" 
                AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="chk" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtSignificantOtherName" runat="server" class="tblTxt txt" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/VnCpP/*